# Using a Java applet in a custom web part

Tags: 2007, web-part

I have a need to integrate a third-party Java applet into a custom web part I wrote. The web part simply loads a user control I created that contains the bulk of the functionality. I added the applet to my user control project and it works fine outside of my SharePoint environment.

I installed the updated web part onto my MOSS 2007 development site and the part's page loads fine. The applet is triggered by clicking a link button on the page, which runs some client-side JavaScript to start it. The problem is nothing seems to happen when I click the link. No error messages appear, and the stuff the applet is supposed to do never occurs. It's as if SharePoint is not allowing it to load. I have the .jar file as an embedded resource in my user control DLL and SharePoint fully trusts this DLL (it's deployed to the bin folder).

Is there anything special I need to do to make the applet work? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Got IE8? Try the developer tools to debug the javascript, see what's going down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by trying to load the .jar file as an embedded resource. My web part basically couldn't find it.

The solution was to create a separate non-WSS web site and store the .jar file there. After that my web part could load it without any problems and everything worked as expected.